# NSExtension - Share - Limit type only to video or only to pictures

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist

I have an extension in my app that allows users to pick pictures or video of their 'Photos/Pictures' app to publish in my app.

I limit the number of pictures to 20 and the limit of videos to 1 by doing the following :
[image]

However, I want my users to select multiple pictures **or** only one video, which is not possible with this configuration.

I have read this post: [NSExtension Share Extension limit Photos count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265065/nsextension-share-extension-limit-photos-count/40742849#40742849)

They explain that I can do a custom validation rule but I have no idea how to write it. Is there any other Activation parameter or can someone help with writing the rule?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a valid answer, oddly I didn't manage to make logical conditions (AND / OR) work in a single subquery so I had to split it :

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie"
    ).@count == 1
    AND
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
    ).@count == 0
).@count == 1
OR
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie"
    ).@count == 0
    AND
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
    ).@count &lt;= 20
).@count &gt;= 1
```

Comment: where are you writing the above code, i am writing in info.plist of exetnsion under NSExtensionActivationRule like so between <string> subquery here </string> but i am getting error in xcode saying unable to read property list from file

Comment: I put this code in the info.plist of my extension like so :
 <key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
   <string> SUBQUERY </string> <All closing tags here>

Answer (score 8):

Apple offers an option to do things like you want. We can take a look at the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8

I modified the `UTI-CONFORMS-TO` items to video and images, and the counts a bit:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
    ).@count &lt;= 20
).@count &gt;= 1
OR
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY(
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.video"
    ).@count == 1
).@count == 1
```

This query should limit the selection to only 1 video or 1 to 20 images. Note that you should specify this query like the following:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>
    --- SUBQUERY HERE ---
    </string>
</dict>
```

I did not test this code and it might not fully work, but it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However I want to limit it to 1 video OR 20 images. Not one or one. If I delete the last @count == 1, will it take the other restrictions in my Info.Plist or will I be able to add 5 videos for example ?

Comment: I see, that was not very clear for me. Give me some time and I will update my answer :)

Comment: I juste realised that I made a mistake in the description. I edit the question. Sorry about that !

Comment: Take a look, I updated the answer. (It will point you in a direction, I could not test it)